# Updating a MYSQL Table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update my MYSQL table based on whether or not the user wants to mark an item off a list. SO if item A is checked, Uncheck it. if item A is unchecked, Check it. When i use my script below nothing happens and I'm not sure why or whats even going wrong. No errors are thrown. This is ran when the user pushes the check button. It sends it to variables id and c.

$_GET['c'] should always be a 1 or a 0, Id is a uniqid()

```
<?php

require_once('db.php');

if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
    echo "You didn't supply a item (id)";
    header('HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed');
    exit();
}

if(!isset($_GET['c'])){
    echo "You didn't supply a item (c)";
    header('HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed');
    exit();
}

if ( $_GET['c'] == 0 )
{
$query = "UPDATE todo_item
          SET checked = 1
          WHERE todo_id = :id";
}
else
{
$query = "UPDATE todo_item
          SET checked = 0
          WHERE todo_id = :id";
}

$id = $_GET['id'];

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement -> execute(array(
    'todo_id' =>$id,
));

header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

Comment: Change `'todo_id' => $id` to `'id' => $id`.

Comment: echo $statement after $statement = $db->prepare($query); and tell what you get plus i am confused about this part $statement -> execute(array(
    'todo_id' =>$id,
));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are passing the wrong parameter to `execute`. Try this:

```
$statement -> execute(array(
    ':id' =>$id,
));
```

Comment: You were right. Its always the stupid little things you cant see with your own eyes because you have looked at it to many times. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are binding `:id` in the prepared statement, but when you execute it, you are passing the array key `todo_id`.  Change it accordingly:

```
$statement -> execute(array(
    ':id' =>$id,
));
```